# Create question in Google Form where all answer options calculate to 100%

Tags: google-forms

I have this question in a survey I'm trying to build a percentage accumulation like so:

> Put the % of how much you spend of your salary in the following
>   categories: [Food, Transport, Health, ...., Other]

I want to format the question in Google Forms such that:

1. For each category, the user can input/select a value between 0%-100%
2. It should validate that the accumulation of the percentages is 100%

I tried Google Forms first, but I was unsuccessful. Any suggestions to do it using Google Forms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Short answer

At this time, this is not possible with Google Forms.

## Explanation

Google Forms doesn't have a question that allows multiple numeric answers and the answer validation only could be set for the related question, not for multiple questions at once.

### New Google Forms question types:

> - Multiple choice
> - Checkbox
> - Short answer
> - Paragraph
> - Dropdown : Respondents choose an answer from a menu that drops down
> - Linear scale : Respondents rank something along a scale of numbers
> - Multiple choice grid : Respondents choose points on a grid

### Old Google Forms question types

> - Text: Respondents provide short answers
> - Paragraph text: Respondents provide longer answers
> - Multiple choice: Respondents select one option from among several
> - Checkboxes: Respondents select as many options as they'd like
> - Choose from a list: Respondents select one option from a dropdown menu
> - Scale: Respondents rank something along a scale of numbers (e.g., from 1 to 5)
> - Grid: Respondents select a point from a two-dimensional grid
> - Date: Respondents use a calendar picker to enter a date
> - Time: Respondents select a time (either a time of day or a duration of time)

## References

- [Add and edit questions, headers, images, videos, and page breaks - Google Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2839737?hl=en)
- [Validate answers in your form - Google Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3378864?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks! I guess I should be looking for alternatives to Google Forms then. Any suggestions?

Comment: You're welcome. Regarding suggestions, consider to post a question at [softwarerecs.se].